# Adding django rest framework endpoints accessible without authentification in django

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I have a django project and a authentication in place. I have django rest framework endpoint

```
class WorkStatViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = WorkStat.objects.all()
    serializer_class = WorkStatSerializer
    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
```

As i understand i should be able to access it without logging in bet i cant. 
I am redirected to the django project main login. how can i create a endpoint accessible without login?

Comment: do you have DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES set up in your settings?

Comment: Yes i do have them set up. i have 'rest_framework.permissions.AllowAny'

Comment: I think the main django project which has authentification is messing with the rest framework. maybe i could override that for that one url i need.

Comment: do you use any specific middleware for auth in the main project?

Comment: I had a middleware interfering and needed to add  LOGIN_EXEMPT_URLS. thanks everyone for making me look in the right places.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
permission_classes = ()
```

That should do the trick. What you have says "allow any auth". This says "there's no auth"